# Определить активное окно

Tags: java

Можно ли посредством Java определить имя окна, которое активно в данный момент? Если можно, то как?
Все, что я нахожу, определяет активность окна самой программы. Но это не то.

Comment: Используйте нативное API, без него никак.

Comment: Кхм... что такое окно? В Х-Window, Windows, Swing или Android?